# List slicing without numpy

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have the `ohlc` list as below:

```py
ohlc = [["open", "high", "low", "close"],
        [100, 110, 70, 100],
        [200, 210, 180, 190],
        [300, 310, 300, 310]]
```

I want to slice it as:

```py
[["open"],[100],[200],[300]]
```

We can easily slice that list using `numpy`, but I don't know how to do it without `numpy`'s help.

I tried the method listed below but it didn't show the value I wanted:

```py
ohlc[:][0]
ohlc[:][:1]
ohlc[0][:]
```

Comment: `[[t] for t in next(zip(*ohlc))]`

Comment: The above comment is the best answer by far. I would +1 it if posted as an answer. Translating it into human-readable English: transpose the square matrix and get the first row. And to get it as a list just do `[list(_) for _ in zip(*ohlc)][0]`.

Comment: Could someone explain why the answer from @inspectorG4dget is (maybe) better than the one suggested by @Guy ? By using `zip` we also access the whole memory of `ohlc` no ? So I'm not sure to understand the advantage here.

Comment: @obchardon: `zip` does not create the entire answer all at once. As of python3, zip is a generator, which lazily evaluates each tuple. Therefore O(1) space and O(n) runtime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`zip` function](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) gets you tuples containing elements from the `i`-th index of every sublist:

```
In [217]: ohlc = [["open", "high", "low", "close"], 
     ...:         [100, 110, 70, 100], 
     ...:         [200, 210, 180, 190], 
     ...:         [300, 310, 300, 310]] 
     ...:

In [218]: for t in zip(*ohlc): print(t)
('open', 100, 200, 300)
('high', 110, 210, 310)
('low', 70, 180, 300)
('close', 100, 190, 310)
```

You're looking for the first one of these, you call on your friend `next()`.

```
In [219]: next(zip(*ohlc))                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Out[219]: ('open', 100, 200, 300)
```

But that's just a single tuple with all the elements and not a list of lists like you wanted, so use a list comprehension:

```
In [220]: [[t] for t in next(zip(*ohlc))]
Out[220]: [['open'], [100], [200], [300]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over the list and take the element in index in every sub list

```
ohlc = [["open", "high", "low", "close"],
        [100, 110, 70, 100],
        [200, 210, 180, 190],
        [300, 310, 300, 310]]

index = 0
result = [[o[index]] for o in ohlc] # [['open'], [100], [200], [300]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Can it be the right solution this?

```
list_ = []
for i in ohlc:
   list_.append((i[0]))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def slice_list(input):
    ans = []
    for x in input:
        ans.append(x[0])
    return ans
```